Adding custom fields to PgMetadata HTML Templates in QGIS
I am currently working with the PgMetadata plugin for QGIS, and I am trying to add a custom field (test) to the metadata HTML template. Here's the situation:
I have successfully added the test field to the pgmetadata.dataset table in my PostgreSQL database, and it contains values.
Other fields like title and abstract are working perfectly in the HTML templates, but adding [% test %] does not display any value.
I understand that the HTML templates are stored in the pgmetadata.html_template table and use placeholders like [% title %] to display fields.
My questions are:
Is there a specific way to register new fields like test so they can be dynamically included in the HTML templates?
Do I need to make changes to the pgmetadata.html_template table or another part of the PgMetadata setup to include custom fields?
Has anyone successfully extended PgMetadata to include custom fields, and if so, what steps did you take?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Any Question containing "My questions are"... is a candidate for closure. Please [Edit] the Question to ask one question.
